# When to use AuthenticationProvider vs AbstractGuardAuthenticator?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8

I am building a passwordless sign-in system for app, with the ability to sign users out (by invalidating their token).

After reading the Symfony documentation, I still cannot understand when I should use my own `AuthenticationProvider` vs `AbstractGuardAuthenticator`.

What are the main differences? Which one would better suit my case?

Comment: Use the Guard component if at all possible.  The Guard component is fairly new and was designed to simplify custom authenticators.  And does a great job.  When Symfony was released the AuthenticationProvider as the only choice and took a lot of work.  The AuthenticationProvider is still used under the hood as it were but use the guard unless you hit an extreme edge condition.

Comment: @Cerad Thanks for the tip. After some investigation I can see now too that these two are somewhat similar, the Guard may be easier to wire up (still working on it).